# Go To Report action in SSRS 2008, Sharepoint Integrated mode doesn't do anything

Tags: sharepoint, ssrs-2008

I've created two reports in the same project, and the first report has an Action "Go To Report" in a tablix cell, to take it to this subreport I'll call SecondRpt.rdl.  When I run it in BIDS, the action works fine.  I deploy the reports to Sharepoint, and when I click on the cell, nothing happens, no err message or anything.  I've read that the report name should have the ".rdl" appended, so tried that, still nothing.  I've also tried putting in the folder path to the SecondRpt.rdl, again nothing happens.  Is there a setting in Sharepoint that we've missed?  I don't know anything about how Sharepoint is set up, but the admin will help if it's something on that side.
I've seen where I can accomplish the same objective if I use the Go To URL option, but this method seems much simpler to set up.
Any advice is appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

sorry for the necro but:

I was having the same issue: everything works fine in BIDS but click on the cell after deployment and nothing happens. Tried adding the .rdl ext and still nothing.

The cell in question had a concatenation of 2 field values (item id + ":" + item desc)- once I moved the values in to seperate fields everything worked fine. :/